# How to callback with an argument which gets declared in event

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make the following work.
Basically after the onReadyStateChange event, it should alert the result trough the function cb(). Altough it doesn't really seem to work. It just doesn't do anything.
How can I make this work?

Thank you.

```
loadDoc();
function loadDoc() {
  POST("http://foobar.com/", "POST", "{foo: bar}", cb);
}

function cb(r){
    alert(r);
}

function POST(url, method, json, callback){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      function x(){ callback(xhttp.responseText); }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open(method, url, true);
  xhttp.send(json);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are never calling the function `x`. Why do you put the call to the callback inside `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the callback in another function, just do this.

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  callback(xhttp.responseText);
}
```